# Send Email based on value in cell 1 respectively from column's list aliases in Sheet 2

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script

Ive checked most available resources her and still straggling with following:

I 'manually' set value in Sheet defined in Settings:
eg SampleEmail;
values are Option 1, Option 2, Option 3,
whereas email aliases I keep in Settings.sheet

So I would like to send email (on Run.Trigger) which match
eg if Option 1 in SampleEmail.Sheet then Send Email with Settings.Sheet Option 1 associated EmailAdress

```
function sendEmail() {
    var settingsSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("BugSettings");
    var mainSheetName = settingsSheet.getRange("B1").getValue();

    var mainSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainSheetName);

    var lastRow = mainSheet.getLastRow();
    var lastRowSet = settingsSheet.getLastRow();
    var startRow = settingsSheet.getRange("B2").getValue();

    for (i = 0; i < lastRow - 1; i++) {
        var currentRow = i + startRow;
        var isEmailSent = mainSheet.getRange("K" + currentRow).getValue();

        var componentName = mainSheet.getRange("A" + currentRow).getValue();
        var recipient = settingsSheet.getRange("A" + lastRowSet).getValue();
        var emails = settingsSheet.getRange("B" + lastRow).getValue();
        var email = ''; // If we don't find a match, we'll fail the send
        for (var row = 0; row < componentName.length; row++) {
            if (componentName[row][0] == recipient) {
                email = emails[row][0];

                if (isEmailSent == "") {
                    var owner = "OWNER: " + mainSheet.getRange("B" + currentRow).getValue();
                    var milestone = "MILESTONE: " + mainSheet.getRange("C" + currentRow).getValue();
                    var sourceDoc = "SOURCE DOCUMENT:  " + settingsSheet.getRange("B5").getValue();
                    var dateAdded = "DATE ADDED: " + mainSheet.getRange("G" + currentRow).getValue();
                    var message = "<P>" + owner + "," + "<P>" + milestone + "," + "<P>" + sourceDoc + "," + "<P>" + dateAdded + ","

                    var subjectMilestone = mainSheet.getRange("C" + currentRow).getValue();
                    var subjectAI = mainSheet.getRange("D" + currentRow).getValue();
                    var subject = [subjectMilestone + subjectAI];

                    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, "", {
                        htmlBody: message,
                        name: "My Name"
                    });

                    mainSheet.getRange("K" + currentRow).setValue("Yes");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Added sample code - Im pretty new in Apps Script so it might not look to pretty!

Comment: thanks for the link - just verified it. This probably still way to go?